# Union type of array elements in ambient context

Tags: arrays, typescript, union

So I'm working on a typings and trying to get a list of an array elements in a union type.
For example, I got an array of strings that will be passed into a method in a class:

```
['test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3']
```

And the type and output type should be:

```
type ArrayElements<T extends string[]> = ??? 
// 'test' | 'test1' | 'test2' | 'test3'
```

I know that you can do `as const` in normal typescript, but any usage of `as` in a typescript defenitions file will result a syntax error...

Any ideas?

Comment: It would just be `T[number]`, but could you please provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?  That array is just sitting there, is it a value or a type?  Is it assigned to a variable or given a type name?  Show how you plan to *use* `ArrayElements`, with example code.

Comment: nvm, solved it but thanks anyways :)